# CSS Signature - Font-weight not changing to desired

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to create an email signature using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"> 
 <title>padthai wokbar</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aKtZEo7.png" width="105px" alt="padthai wokbar">
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;font-family: Helvetica Neue;font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none;color:#424040">
    <div style="
                  color: #424040; 
                  font-size: 16px;
                  font-weight: 900;
                  ;">test</div>


    <div style="font-weight: 500;">Managing Director</div>


    <div><a style="font-weight: 300;">Email:</a><a style='font-family: Helvetica Neue; text-decoration: none; color:#424040; font-weight:300 !important;'  a href='mailto:test'> test@padthaiwokbar.com</a></div>
    <div><a style="font-weight: 300;">Tel:</a><a style='font-family: Helvetica Neue; text-decoration: none; color:#424040; font-weight:300 !important;'  a href='tel:test'>+test</a></div>
    <div> <a style='font-family: Helvetica Neue; text-decoration: none;color:#424040; font-weight:300;' a href='http://www.padthaiwokbar.com' target='blank';>test</a></div>
    <div> <a style='font-family: Helvetica Neue; text-decoration: none;color:#424040; font-weight:300;' a href='https://www.google.hu/maps/place/Budapest,+Csemete+u.+10,+1036/@47.5286934,19.0358274,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4741d956f0a595ab:0xb000c2f0e41e315b!8m2!3d47.5286934!4d19.0380161' target='blank';>test</a></div>
</div>
```

[This is how I would like it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5d3y.png)

[This is how it looks in GMAIL.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QED8v.png)

It does not seem to care about what I set as font-weight, any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Sorry if the css is a bit hard to read, I was just experimenting with what might be causing the issue

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the font used on your system actually support the font weight you've specified? If it doesn't, it'll fall back to a weight that it has.

Comment: Yes, I have made another Signature which uses the same font, and its weight -  300, no trouble there. Also, brackets renders it fine, it's only GMAIL and some other mail clients that make it appear like that. @Terry

Comment: You mean the font renders differently on another machine? Or on the same machine but on different mail clients?

Comment: The text renders fine in brackets, but differently in mail clients (seems to me like something is overriding font-weight, but can't seem to figure out what... No other machines involved. :) @terry